# Error when trying to save MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error when trying to save MySQL table structure.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BINARY NOT NULL, `rank` INT(5000) BINARY NULL) ENGINE = InnoDB
>   CHARACTER SET utf' at line 1

I've tried to change all of the settings to something different but I can't figure it out. This field will hold a value that equals the number of times a visitor to my site has clicked a like button.

[image: Creating the table in phpMyAdmin]

Comment: More details, please. ¿Are you creating the table using PHPMyadmin? (your screenshot corresponds to that) By typing SQL statements by hand? In that case, please post them. Also, post the parameters you're using in PHPMyadmin, if that's what you are using.

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` query are are trying to run?

Comment: Why are all the fields `BINARY`?  I don't think `DATETIME` fields can be `BINARY`.

Comment: I am using PHPMyadmin. I have type set to text. length/values set to 5000. Default set to none. Collation set to utf8_unicode_ci. Attributes set to primary.

Comment: The only options it gives me for attributes is binary, unsigned, unsigned zerofill and  on update current_timestamp.

Comment: @JoeElmore: You can just leave it blank, can't you?

Comment: I did that. Thanks Rocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your `attributes` column, you are setting *all* your fields to [`BINARY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html).  Why are you doing that?

Doing this will turn your `TEXT` fields into `BLOB` fields, and I don't think that's really necessary here.

Your `DATETIME` (and the `INT` field, I think) can't be set to `BINARY`, that doesn't make any sense so MySQL throws an error.

Just leave that "attributes" field blank unless you *really* need to change it.